# Why this pointer got a Segmentation fault C?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Just as the follow code,the intcmp1 runs correctly but the intcmp gets a segment fault.I don't know why.These two codes looks as same.

My system environment is: OS X 10.10.2 64bit ; clang

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int intcmp(const void *v1, const void *v2){ //Segment Fault
    return (*((int*)(*(int*)v1)) - *((int*)(*(int*)v2)));
}
int intcmp1(const void *v1, const void *v2){ //No Problem
    return (**(int**)v1-**(int**)v2);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[5]={0,1,2,3,4};
    int **b,i;
    b=calloc(5,sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){b[i]=&a[i];}

    printf("cmp1 begin\n");
    qsort(b,5,sizeof(int*),intcmp1);
    printf("cmp1 end\n");
    printf("cmp1 begin\n");
    qsort(b,5,sizeof(int*),intcmp);
    printf("cmp2 end\n");
}
```

Isn't `**((int**)a)` equal as `*((int*)(*(int*)a))`?

Comment: Why would you expect the first version to work?  You're passing an int**, but casting to an int*.

Comment: How they look the same? `int*` is not `int**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `**((int**)a)` and `*((int*)(*(int*)a))` are not equivalent.  The first one is correct in the context: `a` is indeed a pointer to an element of the array of `int*` passed to `qsort`.  `**((int **)a)` or simply `**(int**)a` reads the integer you want to compare.

Conversely, the expression `*((int*)(*(int*)a))` does something different: it reads from the same address in memory, but as an `int` and then pretends this `int` is actually an address and attempts to read from that address.  If `int` and addresses don't have the same width, this will fail spectacularly. It they happen to be the same size, it will succeed non portably.

Furthermore, you cannot reliably compare `int` values by just subtracting one from the other.  For example `INT_MIN < 1` but `INT_MIN - 1` invokes undefined behaviour and most likely computes to `INT_MAX`, a positive value.

`intcmp1` should be rewritten this way:

```
int intcmp1(const void *v1, const void *v2) { // works better
    return (**(int**)v1 > **(int**)v2) - (**(int**)v1 < **(int**)v2);
}
```

The `<` and `>` comparison operators return `1` or `0`, thus `imtcmp1` will return `-1`, `0` or `1` precisely.

Comment: This code can run at Windows and Ubuntu,where sizeof(int)=4 sizeof(int*)=8,as same as OS X. How could I make this run correctly on OS X without edit the code? Thank you very much

Comment: @Jxy: which code? Your code might run on OS/X if you compile with `-m32`, forcing 32 bit mode where `sizeof(int)== sizeof(int*)`